# Deployed Azure python function, can not run because 'azure.storage' module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

After deploying my Python Function App, when I try to run it on Azure cloud, it fails with  the following error: How can I install azure-storage on the machine running the app service? Please help.

import azure.functions as func
import datetime

import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
.....
......

Comment: the error: -----
exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 230, in _

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file containing the packages that your function requires? [link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#python-version-and-package-management)

Comment: Yes, this is the content of the txt file azure-storage-blob==1.5.0
azure-storage-common==1.4.2
azure-storage-file==1.4.0
azure-storage-queue==1.4.0
azure-functions
azure-functions-worker
grpcio==1.14.1
grpcio-tools==1.14.1
protobuf==3.6.1
six==1.11.0

Comment: And then I get this error on deployment if I have the requirements.txt populated with the above:      There was an error restoring dependencies.ERROR: cannot install cryptography-2.7 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-native-deps option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish

Comment: @D Workie it looks like the More information link in the Error message describes the necessary next steps. Let us know if it's still not working after trying that.

Comment: @Thmsdnnr  Thank you so much for pointing that out. I actually followed that and did not work. However after fresh install of the Core tools and Docker, I managed to build the package and run it. This is the build command I used:  func azure functionapp publish <app name> --build-native-deps

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your Azure CLI or You can Open Azure CLI from the Azure portal as well.

**Create Storage Account:**

az storage account create --name  --location  --resource-group  --sku Standard_LRS

*Ex:-*
az storage account create --name apistorage --location westindia --resource-group  apiGroup --sku Standard_LRS

**Create Resource Group:**

az group create --name  --location

*Ex:-*
az group create --name apiGroup --location westindia

**Now you can create your azure function from CLI:**

*Ex:-* 
az functionapp create --resource-group apiGroup --os-type Linux --consumption-plan-location westindia  --runtime python --name ServiceName --storage-account  apistorage

*Reference:*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Comment: This was resolved actually. It turned out to be, I need to create requirement file and Docker container.